# xamarin android (not forms) button tag

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to pass some additional information with a button press. From what I could gather reading on the web I should use a button tag.

So far I have this

```
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.Text = "Test Button";
        button.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
        button.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
        button.Tag = "hello";
        button.Click += ClickEvent;
```

And this is the handler:

```
    public void ClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Android.Widget.Button button = (Android.Widget.Button)sender;

        var test = button.Tag;
    }
```

This works, but I need to be able to pass 3 ints of data. I have tried using an array but I have no idea how to read it in the handler as it comes back as a java.object.
Can anyone please push me in the right direction?

Comment: google `xamarin android convert .net int to from java.lang.object`. I wouldn't try to pass an array. Instead, make a `List` (or `Dictionary`) that holds the needed info for each button. Then for tag, store List index (or Dictionary key). Perhaps as a string, if that is easier to cast to/from java.lang.object. If you get this working, consider adding "Your Answer" below, to help others in the future.

Comment: I guess that will work. As suggested I have a dictionary with the key equal to the names of my units as a string, I set button.tag = "name" then inside the ClickEvent I get the value. Bit of a oddball way of doing it but it works. Thanks